# setBackground and getBackground method for Build.version < 16

Tags: java, android, version, compatibility

I have a problem with **getBackground()** and **setBackground()** method. I have designed an application, but now I found out that I didn't check which version is user android system (I am beginner to android - good lesson).

My aplication is working on Build.version > 15, because methods mentioned above were introduced in this version.

**I would like to use similar method that existed before version 16. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`getBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground%28%29) method has been around since API level 1, so that shouldn't be a problem. Only [`setBackground(Drawable background)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) was introduced starting API level 16 and may thus cause problems on older platforms.

Your alternatives are:

1. [`setBackgroundColor(int color)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)
2. [`setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)
3. [`setBackgroundResource(int resid)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Of these methods, the second one has been deprecated since API level 16, as it was replaced with the `setBackground(Drawable background)` you're currently using. However, if you look at the actual implementation for that method, you'll see the following:

```
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    //noinspection deprecation
    setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}
```

So all it does at this point is delegate the call to the deprecated `setBackgroundDrawable()` method. Hence, if you want a quick fix, just change your code to use that one and you're good to go.